# How can I fix this sum of arrays?

Tags: python

This program should sum two arrays using a class. If they don't have the same lenth, an exception is created with assert.

```
class a():
    def __init__(self,arr1,arr2):
        self.arr1=arr1
        self.arr2=arr2
    def sum(self):
        n1=len(self.arr1)
        n2=len(self.arr2)
        assert(n1==n2),"different lenths"
        l=[]
        for i in range (0,n1):
            l[i]=self.arr1[i]+self.arr2[i]
        return l
arr1=[]
arr2=[]
arr1=list(map(int,input().split()))
arr2=list(map(int,input().split()))
array=a(arr1,arr2)
print(array.sum)
```

The problem is that after I give it the input numbers, I obtain this `<bound method a.sum of <__main__.a object at 0x000001DD03005790>>`
What's the problem?

Comment: `print(array.sum)` is printing the method itself. To execute the method and print the result, do `print(array.sum())`.

Answer (score 2):

it should have been `print(array.sum())`, calling to a function/method is done by using parenthesis `()`.

Comment: Thank you, but now it tells me that the list assignment index is out of range

Answer (score 2):

You **always** call a function using `()` parenthesis.

```
<bound method a.sum of <__main__.a object at 0x000001DD03005790>>
```

When you print the statement, you have just referenced the function. That's why it is printing this.

Just do

```
print(array.sum())
```